# Get lowest shared value in a one to many relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a one to many relationship table.

I want to get the lowest other_id that is shared between multiple id's.

```
id other_id
5  5
5  6
5  7
6  6
6  7
7  7
```

I can do this by building an SQL statement dynamically with parts added for each additional id I want to query on. For example:

```
select * from (
    select other_id from SomeTable where id = 5
) as a
inner join (
    select other_id from SomeTable where id = 6
) as b
inner join (
    select other_id from SomeTable where id = 7
) as c
on a.other_id = b.other_id
and a.other_id = c.other_id
```

Is there a better way to do this? More specifically, is there a way to do this that doesn't require a variable number of joins? I feel like this problem probably already has a name and better solutions.

My query gives me the number 7, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the lowest other_id shared between all ids

```
select other_id
from SomeTable
group by other_id
having count(distinct id) = 3
order by other_id limit 1
```

or dynamically

```
select other_id
from SomeTable
group by other_id
having count(distinct id) = (select count(distinct id) from SomeTable) 
order by other_id limit 1
```

or if you want to look for the lowest other_id shared between specific ids

```
select other_id
from SomeTable
where id in (5,6,7)
group by other_id
having count(distinct id) = 3
order by other_id limit 1
```

Comment: It looks like the last option does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

i dont have a mysql server to test it out at the moment, but try a "group by" statement:

```
select 
    other_id 
from 
    SomeTable 
group by 
    other_id having count(*) > 1 
order by 
    other_id asc 
    limit 1
```

Comment: Why not us min instead of limit 1 and order by?

Comment: It doesn't seem like that does what I want.

Comment: in your data set, aren't you looking for the number 6 to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) for simple query

```
 SELECT MIN(other_id) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Though, there seems to be working solutions I want to add my version, just to show, how smart I am ;-)

```
SELECT other_id FROM SomeTable a INNER JOIN SomeTable b on a.other_id=b.other_id ORDER by other_id ASC LIMIT 1
```